# MySQL query that retrieves specific data about users with the same value

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to write a query that will retrieve 2 columns. One column would be the name of a project, and the second column would be the names of the members of that project. What I am getting is a list with information of each member rather than each project. Meaning I am getting a repeat of the project names at times, if there are multiple members in the project. How can i just show the project names once, with the team members on the second column? Thank you.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT p.project_name
                  , s.student_name 
               FROM Projects p 
               LEFT
               JOIN Students s 
                 ON p.project_id = s.student_id

    project_name       student_name
    space exploration  Brian 
    space exploration  Steve 
    space exploration  Finn 
    Advanced Java      Kay
    Advanced Java      John
    Cryptography       Jake
    Cryptography       Andy
    ABC                NULL
```

Comment: At a minimum, edit your question and type your query in as text.  The image is just about unreadable.  Sample data, desired results, and a SQL Fiddle are also always welcome.

Comment: p.project_id = s.student_id? This is unlikely, to say the least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT p.project_name, GROUP_CONCAT(s.student_name)
FROM Projects p  LEFT JOIN
     Students s 
     ON p.project_id = s.student_id
GROUP BY p.project_name;
```

This will put the students into a comma-delimited list.